# nginx динамическое значение (регулярное выражение) в location

Tags: nginx

прошу помощи, мне необходимо в директиве location указать не статику а динамическое значение

```
    location /my/path/5/
    {
        index index.php;
    }
```

где, вместо 5 может быть любая цифра. Явно указываю 5 - работает, начинаю изгаляться что то типа вместо 5 подставляю `[\d]{1,2}` к примеру - не работает. Подскажите правильный синтаксис

Comment: А зачем это вообще? В 80% случаев никаких регулярок и не нужно. Попробуйте лучше описать цель

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение

```
    location ~ /my/path/([0-9]*)/$
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в [location](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) используется регулярное выражение, то нужно использовать перед регуляркой модификаторы `~` или `~*`. Т.к. вы их не использовали, то ваши эксперименты были безуспешными.

По возможности нужно использовать префиксные выражения, это будет более производительно. Например для вашего случая мог бы подойти такой означает "все что начинается с /my/path/":

```
location ^~ /my/path/
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, я уже разобрался!